# Php regex multiline search issue

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get all  characters between style tag.
this is my regex

```
 '#<style>(.*?)</style>'
```

It is producing result correctly
However it is not working for multi line

Working correctly for this :

```
<style>body { height: '100%'; }</style>
```

This is not working

```
<style> 
body { 
  height: '100%'; 
}

</style>
```

I know /s or [/s/S] or s would work but I dont how they will work

Regards

Comment: Use this regex: `'#<style>(.*?)</style>#s'`

Comment: you're answer was the first answer and correct one for me , but could not  accept answer as it is  a comment. Anyways , thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pattern modifiers to match on multilines with PCRE regex : http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

`m` is the multiline modifier. `s` is the modifier to allow dot to match new lines too. So how about a pattern like this one:

```
'#<style>(.*?)</style>#ms'
```

I think you can also be interested in the `i`modifier since tags can be worded `<style>` or `<STYLE>` or other flavors `<StYlE>` wich are all valid.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
 <style>([\s\S]*)<\/style>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fO9dY8/1)

Answer (score 0):

"." matches any single character except \n，so `'<style>(.*?)</style>'` wouldn't work in multi line situation. while [\s\S]* will match any character including \n.